# Filament - Form builder -> Select: I use selects not related with Model and get error "Add fillable property [...] to allow mass assignment on [...]."

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Below is my resource (key fragments):

```
<?php

class CustomLogicResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = CargoCustomLogic::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-rectangle-stack';

    public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
    {
        /** @var Company $company */
        $company = Filament::getTenant();

        return parent::getEloquentQuery()
            ->where('company_id', $company->id)
            ->select([
                'id',
                'company_id',
                'type',
                'partner_ids',
                'target_ids',
                'load_points',
                'unload_points',
                'config',
                'position',
                'contact_ids',
            ])
            ->with([
                'partners',
                'targets',
                'contacts',
            ]);
    }

    public static function prepare(Collection|array $selection, mixed $displayedAttribute = 'name'): array
    {
        try {
            $result = [];

            foreach ($selection as $item) {
                $result[$item['id']] = $item[$displayedAttribute];
            }

            return $result;
        } catch (Throwable $throwable) {
            return [];
        }
    }

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Section::make('Conditions')
                    ->description('...')
                    ->schema([
                        Select::make('type')
                            ->required()
                            ->options(CustomLogic::TYPES_TEXT)
                            ->label('Type'),

                    ]),

                Section::make('Load conditions')
                    ->description('...')
                    ->schema([
                        Select::make('load_points_city')
                            ->label('Load city')
                            ->searchable()
                            ->getSearchResultsUsing(fn (string $search) => City::where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->limit(50)->pluck('name', 'id'))
                            ->getOptionLabelUsing(fn ($value): ?string => City::find($value)?->name),

                    ]),

                Section::make('Default value')
                    ->schema([
                        Select::make('cargo_type_id')
                            ->label('Cargo type')
                            ->getSearchResultsUsing(fn (string $search) => CargoType::where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->limit(50)->pluck('name', 'id'))
                            ->getOptionLabelUsing(fn ($value): ?string => CargoType::find($value)?->name)
                            ->searchable(),

                    ]),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'create' => Pages\CreateCustomLogic::route('/create'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditCustomLogic::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Below is my EditCustomLogic class (key fragments):

```
<?php

class EditCustomLogic extends EditRecord
{
    protected static string $resource = CustomLogicResource::class;

    protected function getHeaderActions(): array
    {
        return [
            Actions\ViewAction::make(),
            Actions\DeleteAction::make(),
        ];
    }

    protected function beforeFill(): void
    {
        dump('beforeFill'); // doesn't reach here
    }

    protected function afterFill(): void
    {
        dump('afterFill'); // doesn't reach here
    }

    protected function beforeValidate(): void
    {
        dump('beforeValidate'); // doesn't reach here
    }

    protected function afterValidate(): void
    {
        dump('afterValidate'); // doesn't reach here
    }

    protected function beforeCreate(): void
    {
        dump('beforeCreate'); // doesn't reach here
    }

    protected function afterCreate(): void
    {
        dump('afterCreate'); // doesn't reach here
    }

    protected function mutateFormDataBeforeCreate(array $data): array
    {
        dd($data); // doesn't reach here

        // removing data keys that are not in model and not in $fillable = [...] array -> for test
        unset(
            $data['load_points_city'],
            $data['load_points_region'],
            $data['unload_points_region'],
            $data['cargo_type_id'],
            $data['pack_type_id'],
            $data['truck_types'],
            $data['load_types'],
            $data['additional_equipment'],
            $data['additional_conditions'],
        );

        dd($data); // doesn't reach here

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Filament render all of fields - as for attributes and relationships that are in the model as for properties that are not in model.

I get error after clicking the save button:

> {"result":"Internal Server
> Error","status_code":500,"debug":{"message":"Add fillable property
> [load_points_city, load_points_region, unload_points_region,
> cargo_type_id, pack_type_id, truck_types, load_types,
> additional_equipment, additional_conditions] to allow mass assignment
> on [Modules\Cargo\Models\CargoCustomLogic]."

These fields (which are not among model properties and relations) should not be in $fillable. It is necessary to solve the problem using **Filament** without “reinventing wheels”, “inserting crutches” and any bad practices.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, `Add fillable property... to allow mass assignment` means that the `Model` has to define the `fillable` attributes.

Check that your `Model`s have something like this:

```php
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
];
```

where `name`, `email` and `password` are an example for a `User` model.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#mass-assignment